# How do I exclude a markdown file from YARD?

Tags: ruby, yard

[My project](https://github.com/momentohq/client-sdk-ruby/) has a `README.template.md` file which should not be parsed by YARD.

I've used --exclude for certain .rb files, but I can't seem to exclude this file.

```
$ yard doc --exclude README.template.md 
[warn]: In file `README.template.md':2: Cannot resolve link to { from text:
    ...{{ ossHeader }...
[warn]: In file `README.template.md':2: Cannot resolve link to { from text:
    ...{{ ossHeader }...
[warn]: In file `README.template.md':2: Cannot resolve link to { from text:
    ...{{ ossHeader }...
[warn]: In file `README.template.md':2: Cannot resolve link to { from text:
    ...{{ ossHeader }...
```

I've tried marking it private by adding @private at the top, YARD still parses it.

```
<!--
# @private
-->

{{ ossHeader }}

## Getting Started :running:
```

How can I get YARD to ignore this file?

```
$ yard config
ivars:
  :@symbolize_value: false
elements:
  :load_plugins: false
  :ignored_plugins: []
  :autoload_plugins: []
  :safe_mode: false

$ cat .yardopts 
--no-private
--exclude _pb.rb$
```

Comment: Any chance you have a .yardopts file in the root of your project? yard will use that if it finds it and the file may already have your README.template.md specified in it.

Comment: @FelixD I do, [here it is](https://github.com/momentohq/client-sdk-ruby/blob/main/.yardopts). There isn't much in it. I tried adding the --exclude there as well.

Comment: Do you have any yard plugins installed: >yard config< will display any plugins
I cloned your repo and ran a few tests

Comment: I had to paste my test results in pastebin [test results](https://pastebin.com/zFWxn70v)

Comment: https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/837 might offer some additional insight

Comment: @FelixD I see what's happened. I hadn't generated the README.md yet, so it was deciding that README.template.md is the readme. [If I delete README.md I get the same behavior](https://pastebin.com/jCPTm157).

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Your only choice is to rename the README.template.md to something else :(

### Why Yard does Yard things

This has been a fun deep dive back into ruby. I read through the Yardoc source, specifically the command line parser and found this.

From [Yarddoc Source](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/blob/main/lib/yard/cli/yardoc.rb)
starting at line 287. Let's look at the relevant parts of the "parse_arguments" function

```ruby
# Parses commandline arguments
# @param [Array<String>] args the list of arguments
# @return [Boolean] whether or not arguments are valid
# @since 0.5.6
def parse_arguments(*args)
# --- CODE SNIPPED AWAY ----
  readme = Dir.glob('README{,*[^~]}').
           select {|f| extra_file_valid?(f)}.
           sort_by {|r| [r.count('.'), r.index('.'), r] }.first
# --- CODE SNIPPED AWAY ----
end
```

The code shows it will **always** glob any file that starts with the letters 'README' no matter what follows. This is the default behavior, and the maintainer has [no intention of changing it as of today.](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/1429#issuecomment-1020555444) No judgement,  I agree with the philosophy.

### Solutions

I see a couple of options for you.

1. fork the yard repo, modify the dir.glob to ignore things that have template or other things. The opensource way -- *all in unison* THIS IS THE WAY lol :)
2. Use a YardocTask  - below I modified the Rakefile from your project. Additions are annotated.

Yard provides before and after procs for the [YarddocTask](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/YARD/Rake/YardocTask)

Now this isn't the BEST way to solve the problem. You really shouldn't be shelling out because of... lots of reasons... but it is a working solution. I also am assuming a *nix environment when renaming the file. You should probably change it to use ruby [FileUtils](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/stdlibs/fileutils/FileUtils.html).

```ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "bundler/gem_tasks"
require "rspec/core/rake_task"
# ----------- Start new -------------
require "yard"
# ------------- end new -------------
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)

require "rubocop/rake_task"

RuboCop::RakeTask.new

task default: %i[spec rubocop]

# ----------- Start new -------------
YARD::Rake::YardocTask.new do |t|
  t.before = Proc.new {
    `mv README.template.md _README.template.md`
  }
  t.after = Proc.new {
    `mv _README.template.md README.template.md`
  }
end
# ------------- end new -------------
```

Let me know if you need a deeper explanation. I'll be happy to expand on anything you are unclear on.